# Cron job failed - exit status 2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Hi having trouble with the following cron job;

```
30 07   * * *   root    /usr/bin/tail /var/log/rsnapshot-server.log -n 5 | grep 'completed\|failed' >> /srv/Backup_notify/backup_monitor.txt
```

Basically I want to search the last 5 lines in rsnapshot-server.log for anything matching text 'completed' or 'failed'. The resulting line is then appended to backup_monitor.txt (this is eventually appended by all our Windows backups and emailed daily).

The command will run as root, but I get a permission denied error running sudo (surely this should run??). If the command runs as root, then I'd expect it to run as root through a cron job. But for some reason it doesn't and I get an exit status 2 reported.

Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04.
Backup_notify is a windows share mounted using cifs-utils and windows credentials.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked root's email? `cron` should send the the error messages in an email.

Comment: What happens if you just run the `tail` command without `grep`, does it work?

Comment: sudo tail /var/log/rsnapshot-server.log -n 5 | grep 'completed\|failed'

Comment: returns the correct text, but permission denied when editing the file

Comment: You don't need to use `sudo` when the cron job is running as root. Just to be sure, the cron job is in `/etc/crontab`, right, not root's `crontab -e`.

Comment: What do you mean by editing the file? There's no editing in the cron job.

Comment: >> /srv/Backup_notify/backup_monitor.txt appends the output text from grep to the file.

The cronjob is located in /etc/cron.d as a seperate file (sorry should have mentioned that!) I've been trying to run it as sudo to test, but yes you're correct, the cron job has root permissions and runs it at root, but it's not working.

Comment: Since the output file is on a network share, it may not be permitting root to have write permission. Root's privileges don't automatically go across the network.